# WCF service problem

Tags: wcf, service

I created one wcf service lets called as "myService.svc". From my service I am calling client service lets say "clientService.svc". This client service return data to my wcf service.

Today I start getting exception like "There was no endpoint listening at http://clientService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details...."

So where is this problem probably present inside client service or my service as both service are up so I am not able to figure ut out?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

you web.config has the wrong URL for the client service.  Change it to "http://localhost/clientservice.svc".

Answer (score 1):

Check your endpoint configuration... http://clientService.svc is an invalid uri.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try accesing the WSDL via browser?
It seems like the url is wrong maybe in the client, i think it should be something like http://nameofthehost/clientService.svc

to access the wsdl you should add ".wsdl" at the end of the url

Answer (score 0):

How are you running those services? If you are using asp.net development server, its possible, that you got your services running at different ports today. Your inner service's proxy is configured at some address which isn't valid any more. Check the setting and try refreshing the service (right clicking at solution explorer) and possibly change the address or generate proxy again.